# Java - Passing variable to an interface

Tags: android, interface, retrofit

I am building an android app and i am using Retrofit to retrieve data from API. In this app i have to make 3 calls. The first one is working fine. The code for the first one is below. I have one class

```
public class APIClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

static Retrofit getClient(){

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api_app.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();

    return retrofit;
}
}
```

Also i have this interface

```
@Headers({
        "AppId: 3a97b932a9d449c981b595",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "appVersion: 5.10.0",
        "apiVersion: 3.0.0"
})

@POST("/users/login")
Call<MainUserLogin> logInUser(@Body LoginBody loginBody);
```

The code of the Actvity is this

```
call.enqueue(object : Callback<MainUserLogin> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<MainUserLogin>, response: Response<MainUserLogin>) {

            if (response.code().toString().equals("200")){

                val resource = response.body()

                bearerToken = resource.session.bearerToken

                if (bearerToken.isNotEmpty() && bearerToken.isNotBlank()){
                    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    val  editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
                    editor.putString("bearerToken", bearerToken)
                    editor.commit()

                    BearerToken.bearerToken = bearerToken
                    val i = Intent(this@LoginActivity, UserAccountsActivity::class.java)
                    i.putExtra("bearerToken", bearerToken)
                    startActivity(i)
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }


            }else{

                println("edwedw   "+response.errorBody().string())

                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Incorrect email address or password. Please check and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<MainUserLogin>, t: Throwable) {
            call.cancel()
        }
    })
```

This call is working fine.
With this call i am getting one token. The problem is that i have to pass this token as header to make the second call. So, the second call will be like this.

```
@Headers({
        "AppId: 3a97b932a9d449c981b595",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "appVersion: 5.10.0",
        "apiVersion: 3.0.0",
        "Authorization: "+***Token***
})

@GET("/products")
Call<MainUserLogin> getUseraccounts ();
```

Is there any way to pass the variable from the Activity to the interface to make the Api request?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Retrofit` you can call API's with multiple `headers` as follows

```
@GET("/products")
    Call<MainUserLogin> getUseraccounts(@Header("AppId") String appId, @Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Header("appVersion") String appVersion, @Header("apiVersion") String apiVersion, @Header("Authorization") String token);
```

Instead of

```
@Headers({
        "AppId: 3a97b932a9d449c981b595",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "appVersion: 5.10.0",
        "apiVersion: 3.0.0",
        "Authorization: "+***Token***
})

@GET("/products")
Call<MainUserLogin> getUseraccounts ();
```

this. When you call `getUseraccounts` method you can parse the token that you created from the previous `endpoint`.

Try this and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Once you receive the token, you should save this token in a [global repository](https://medium.com/stuart-engineering/magic-with-kotlin-rxjava-and-the-repository-pattern-af751a451254) since the auth token is something that your app will need in order to make further authenticated api calls.

After that, define a `AuthorizationHeaderInterceptor` which will extend `okhttp3.Interceptor`. Override the `intercept` method of this interceptor to add auth token to your request.

```
@Override
public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) {
    return completeRequest(chain);
}

private Response completeRequest(@NonNull Interceptor.Chain chain) {
    AuthToken authToken = authTokenRepository.get();
    Request.Builder requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder();
    if (authToken != null && chain.request().header(Authorization.NAME) == null) {
        requestBuilder.addHeader(Authorization.NAME, Authorization.getValue(authToken.getIdToken()));
    }
    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
    try {
        return chain.proceed(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The interceptor can be added when you build your okhttpClient.

```
okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(new AuthorizationHeaderInterceptor(authTokenRepository))
```

Note that the `Authorization` class is simple convenience class which encapsulates the authorization header name and value format.

```
public class Authorization {
    public static final String NAME = "Authorization";

    @NonNull
    public static String getValue(@NonNull String accessToken) {
        return String.format("Bearer %s", accessToken);
    }
}
```